# It apparently fails to find the module

Tags: javascript, discord.js

The code is this and when I try to turn my bot on I get a error that it can't find the file to execute the command.

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands')
for(const folder [enter image description here][1]of commandFolders){
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
    for(const file of command_files){
        const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
        if(command.name){
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        }else {
            continue
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the error I get when I turn my bot on.

```
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
      throw err;
      ^
    
    Error: Cannot find module './commands/Fun/8ball.js'
    Require stack:
    - C:\Users\Desktop\Discordproject\handlers\command_handler.js
    - C:\Users\Desktop\Discordproject\index.js
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
        at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
        at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
        at module.exports (C:\Users\Desktop\Discordproject\handlers\command_handler.js:8:25)   
        at C:\Users\famil\Desktop\Discordproject\index.js:11:37
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Desktop\Discordproject\index.js:10:38)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10) {
      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: [
        'C:\\Users\Desktop\\Discordproject\\handlers\\command_handler.js',
        'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Discordproject\\index.js'
      ]
    }
```

Directory Structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your directory structure?

Comment: Alright, here https://kierandapro.wtf/images/lbbcbt.png

Answer (score 0):

Your `command_handler.js` file is inside **/handlers/**. `./` is used to access the *current directory*.

Doing `./commands/` doesn't work because the commands folder is not inside of **/handlers/**

You must first exit the current folder (using `../`), then access.

Change all of the `'./commands'` to `'../commands'`

Comment: I have done that but I get a error but a different error here is the error https://kierandapro.wtf/images/8osu4t.png and here is the code https://kierandapro.wtf/images/us7yr7.png